# Dojo dijit.form.ValidationTextBox help

Tags: javascript, dojo

I try to use first time the Dojo toolkit and I'm facing an error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js"></script>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="" method="post">
      <dl class="zend_form">
        <dt id="teszt-label">
          <label for="teszt" class="required">teszt:
          </label>
        </dt>
        <dd id="teszt-element">
          <input type="text" name="teszt" id="teszt" value="" 
            dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
            regExp="\d{5}" required="true" invalidMessage="asd" />
        </dd>
      </dl>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
      dojo.require("dijit.form.ValidationTextBox");
    // ]]></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I got the script from the second example: http://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/form/ValidationTextbox.html#dijit-form-validationtextbox

The script must validate the input with the given regular expression.
I see in firebug, that it loads all of the required components, but it doesn't work on the input field.

What's wrong?

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but you have no html, head, or body tags and 2 title tags. Throw those in and all your scripts in the head, try again and let us know.

Comment: What's the error? What do you mean by “doesn't work on the input field.” What's the intended behaviour? BTW, you've two `<title>` elements. And you should mark your inline script as [CDATA](http://dorward.me.uk/www/comments-cdata/#mandatory-xhtml).

Comment: @edl: There are html, head and body tags, I'll improve the formatting.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the duplicated title tag, but the other tags don't missing, just stackoverflow formatting it weird. Doesn't work anyway...

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: thanks for formatting, I added now the CDATA. The script must validate the field with the given regular expression.
The code is from here from the second example: http://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/form/ValidationTextbox.html#dijit-form-validationtextbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    dojo.require("dojo.parser");
    dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
        dojo.parser.parse();
    });

// ]]>
</script>
```

This code solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

how about doing this instead?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: true, isDebug: true"></script>
```

`isDebug: true` is set if you want some debug messages appearing on browser's console.

Answer (score 0):

`regExp="\d{5}"` to `regExp: "[\\d]{5}"`